# How to navigate between tabs in angularJS (ionic framework)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I saw [this example on codepen.io](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/GpCst).

So I want to set 3 views per tab (default is ios).

I tried to replace this with old one (with old ion-content):

```
<script id="templates/ios.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="ios">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        tab ios
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
</script>
... // and same code for other
```

and I tried to change js to this:

```
  $scope.demo = 'ios';
  templateUrl: "templates/ios.html";
  $scope.setPlatform = function(p) {
    ...
    $scope.demo = p;
    templateUrl: "templates/"+P+".html";
  };
```

But no success to navigate...

Comment: you can use ion-tabs directive http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionTabs/